# Is there a ruby method to make dates and times more readable?

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, rubygems, sinatra

I'm using an API where the date returned looks something like: `2012-11-30 12:54:59 -0800`. I was wondering if there is a Ruby method that can take that as input and return "Today", for example.

Other preferred output would be things like "About an hour ago", "Just now", "a month ago".

I'm using Sinatra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the [Kronic gem](https://github.com/xaviershay/kronic):

```
Kronic.format(Time.now)
 => "Today" 
Kronic.format(Time.now - 500000)
 => "Last Saturday"
```

Comment: Combined with `Time.parse` this can be really useful.

Comment: Nice. For a sinatra app, this is probably lighter than borrowing Rails' DateHelper for `time_ago_in_words`.

Comment: @tadman Combined with Chronic and dotiw it can be even more fun :) Well, for certain values of fun, but we're all here, so fun it is.

Comment: That seems very cool. I'm not sure how to take my value, for example, `2012-11-30 12:54:59 -0800` and convert it though. Similarly, Kronic doesn't seem to have support for things like "just now", or "4 hours ago" ?

Comment: @tonic `Kronic.format(DateTime.parse("2012-11-30 12:54:59 -0800"))`. If you want something different then look at [dotiw](https://github.com/radar/dotiw) and add on the word "ago". When asking questions it's good to provide more than one example, otherwise it's difficult to know what you actually want.

Answer (score 4):

This is a standard `DateTime` object. You can get all parts of it through properties.

E.g.:

```
d = Date.parse('3rd Feb 2001')
                             #=> #<Date: 2001-02-03 ...>
d.year                       #=> 2001
d.mon                        #=> 2
d.mday                       #=> 3
d.wday                       #=> 6
```

You can use those to make it as readable as you wish. [Ruby DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html)